# Automapper - avoid repetition

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper

My architecture is a WEBAPI.NET Core 2.2 .

It is a basic N-tiers architecture : Controller-> service / domain layer-> data layer (dapper) -> stored procedure.

On 80% of my database tables i have "audit" columns :

- "CreatedBy" which indicates who insert data.
- "CreationDate".
- "UpdatedBy"
  which indicates who update data
- "UpdateDate".

I am using an interface in my DTO and my entity objects :

```
 public interface ITrackable
    {
        public string CreatedBy{ get; set; }

        public string? UpdatedBy{ get; set; }

        public DateTime CreationDate{ get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdateDate{ get; set; }
    }
```

the user "CreatedBy" and "UpdatedBy" comes from a JWT token so i need to .

I have a service in domain layer that gives me the user from the JWT token :

```
public interface IUserService
{
    UserModel GetCurrentUser();
}
```

**Problem :**
whenever i convert my DTO object to my entity with automapper, i have to set the property "CreatedBy" and "UpdatedBy" :

```
public void DoSomethingInMyDomainLayer(Something SomethingDTO) //come from Controller
{
    var currentUser = _userService.GetCurrentUser();
    var myEntity= _mapper.Map<MyEntity>(SomethingDTO);
    myEntity.CreatedBy= currentUser.Email; // this code can be found in many places
    _datalayer.DoSomething(myEntity)
}

public void DoSomethingElseInMyDomainLayer(SomethingElse SomethingElseDTO) //come from Controller
{
    var currentUser = _userService.GetCurrentUser();
    var myOtherEntity= _mapper.Map<MyOtherEntity>(SomethingElseDTO);
    myOtherEntity.CreatedBy= currentUser.Email; // this code can be found in many places
    _datalayer.DoSomethingElse(myOtherEntity)
}
```

I don't want to repeat this code in all method with different entities

```
 myEntity.CreatedBy= currentUser.Email
```

**Remark 1 **

i can't use profile automapper, because i will repeat too :

```
CreateMap<MyDTO, MyEntity>()
                .ForMember(x => x.CreatedBy, opt => CallMyUserServiceToGetUserFromJwtToken);
CreateMap<MyDTO2, MyEntity2>()
                .ForMember(x => x.CreatedBy, opt => CallMyUserServiceToGetUserFromJwtToken);
```

**Remark 2 **

I would like a kind of generic mapping :

like "If my Entity Is "ITrackable" i map UserCreatedBy automatically on my Entity.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you

PS : Sorry for my english, it's not my native language

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: thank you, it solve my problem :)